# access macro to copy record contents

Tags: vba, ms-access, copy, record

(Apologies if this is a dumb question - I'm a complete tyro here)

Suppose you have open a Customers table,
with fields Id, LastName, FirstName. The user
selects a record (row) of the table with the
mouse. At this point I'd like to be able to run
a macro that:

(1) reads the fields in the selected record
(2) opens an existing form say FormA
(3) Pastes (writes) the LastName element of
    the record read in (1) into the XYZ field
    of FormA

I've looked through the available macro actions
and I don't see how to do (1). Can anyone help?
(If it can't be done via a macro, how about VBA?).
I can probably figure out how to do (2) and (3)
but if it's not too much to ask, I'd certainly
appreciate some guidance here too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, trying to run a macro or code on a table from the table to update a form is not going to work. Besides, you are not actually updating anything in the target form. You are adding a record. Record actions have very little to do with "forms" and everything to do with the database.

Second, the action you want is a SQL insert (create a new record). It might be possible to do via a macro or a query. VBA is the better choice.

Put a command button on a form. Let the user select the record and click the button. (OnClick event)

Run code behind (write your SQL statement and run it as DoCmd.RunSQL to copy the record from wherever it is (table) to wherever you want it (table). You can add the code to open another form showing the new record if you want.